# Column entries appear as NaN when converting an ODS file to EXCEL/CSV in Python

Tags: pandas, ods

I am trying to convert an ODS file to XLSX/CSV using Python.  The code snippet is shown below:

```
import odf
import pandas as pd
pd.read_excel("filename.ods")
```

The file gets converted to a Pandas data frame, however, all the column entries are NaN.  Further, the column names appear as "unnamed 1", "unnamed 2", etc., instead of the column names contained in the original ODS file.  Is there a way to resolve this issue?

A snapshot of the data is included below.

[image: ODS file]

Comment: can you share sample of your data? how does it look before you try and read it?

Comment: I think you need to set engine to ODF with replace your code to `pd.read_excel("filename.ods", engine='odf')`.

Comment: I had included engine = 'odf', but it did not solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I created a (simple) example, and cannot reproduce the problem.

```
import odf
import pandas as pd 
xls = pd.read_excel("filename.ods",engine="odf")
xls.to_excel("filename.xlsx")
```

[image]

My conclusion (from this) is that more debugging info about your `.ods` file is needed to reproduce, and solve, this problem.